# Fastest way to take top N closest vectors by cosine distance

Tags: java, algorithm, vector

I have a huge list of vectors (~100k) (representing words and calculated using random indexing) and have to find given 1 input word the top N closest vectors. The way I'm doing it now is do a complete sort by distance and then extract the top N results but this takes too much time to be usable, as I have to compute 100k distances. Is there a more efficient way to do it? The vectors are already normalized, so I just have to compute the dot product when calculating the distance.

The vectors are stored in a a Java `HashMap<String, Vector>`, where Vector is la4j class for sparse vectors.

Comment: Are you looking for an algortihm that takes less than linear time, then?

Comment: Yes, or linear with respect to the top N results I want to take and not 100k (total size), if this is possible.

Comment: You are finding the nearest point to one of the ones in your set right? If so you want a spatial data structure like a kd-tree.

Comment: Do you have a good ballpark idea of what "too far away to be likely" is?  If so calc sqrt(distance), and do a quick check if any delta is greater than that, (no serious math, just an abs and a diff), and eliminate a lot of the vectors.  Then sort what remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your vectors into a spatial-aware container, such as [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) or [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or [PK-Tree](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.11.7938).

This way you’ll be able to find the points without iterating through all your dataset, by only looking in a few adjacent cells. Don‘t forget you’ll need to search not just in a single cell, but in the adjacent cells as well, and in multi-dimensional space there’re a lot of neighbors.

**Update:** You still need to measure the distance manually. However, you will not need to iterate through all vectors.

One simple solution — define max distance, iterate all vectors within the cells within that distance, sort, pick the top N.

The most optimal solution (much harder to develop) — iterative search process. For example, start with the single cell where your input vector vX is, find N closest vectors in this cell. If the distance between vX and the N-th found vector (the farthest one) is less than the distance between vX and the nearest point of any cell that’s not yet being searched, then you have your N results. Otherwise, add the vectors from the nearest cell that was not yet searched, and repeat the process. The most complex thing here — keeping track on what cells are already searched and what to do next (esp. for the PK-tree where the tree is of variable height).

The tradeoff solution (not that hard to develop, could be reasonably optimal for you) — iterative search process where you go up the tree all the time. You start with the leaf node containing the vX, if it doesn’t have N vectors or if the vX is closer to a boundary of the cell then the N-th found vector, you go one level up, and add the complete sub-tree starting from the parent node. This way the algorithm is much simpler because the searched area is always rectangular. However, the worst case (which is, if vX lies on the border between the 2 root cells), is much worse — you’ll have to iterate through all your 100k points.

Comment: What's the distance measure that is used in a k-d tree or similar structures? I guess I can't use something like cosine similarity but the way distance is measured is determined and fixed according to the the structure at hand. Am I correct?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with how the spatial-aware containers work.  When adding all the vectors, doesn't they have to compute something vaguely distance-like (at least location-like) in order to determine which cell to use?  I'm not from Missouri, but you'd have to "show me" that this is faster than the brute force calculate all the distances method.

Comment: Drat, I thought of something a minute late to edit my comment.  Do the spatial-aware containers require a sqrt() or similar "slow" function?  If so, you'd have to "show me" that they beat distance.  If not, I will tend to believe you.  :-)

Comment: “doesn't they have to compute something vaguely distance-like” — distance to what? “at least location-like” — the vector is already a location, you don’t need to calculate anything. “require a sqrt() or similar slow function?” — definitely not, that trees are just various methods to divide space by axis-aligned planes into irregular or semi-regular rectangular cells, thus localizing data points.

Comment: @Soonts At some point the algorithm has to compare the location of the vector to the boundaries of the cells.  But, I see that everything can be done in Cartesian coords so no sqrts.  And the tree makes the search log(N)-ish for good speed.  Assuming you can readily find cells that are "near" the target vector, this should be an excellent solution.  I'll give you an upvote!

Comment: However, that trees are relatively hard to correctly implement and debug. And, if the regular grid approach will work (i.e. if the average density of vectors is constant), hashmap will be much faster, about O(1), see my second answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your vectors are more or less evenly distributed in your N-dimensional space, you don’t need all that complexity with the spatial trees.

Instead, you can split your space into regular hypercubic grid so that average grid cell contains under 20 vectors, and store the cells in `HashMap<List<Integer>, List<Vector>>` where the keys are integer coordinates of the grid cell, and values are list of vectors that are inside the corresponding cells.